# Angular 7 - multiline strings on tooltip

Tags: jquery, angular, string, typescript, string-interpolation

I have created multi line string using Template strings.

```html
toolTip = `
      ${Test}  : ${number}
      ${Test}  : ${number}
      ${Test}  : ${number}
      ${Test}  : ${number}
      ${Test}  : ${number}}`;
```

This multi line string I'm showing on tooltip of button , however, extra spaces are getting added from the second line
e.g I'm getting output like below

```
Test string : 123
  Test string2 : 234
  Test string3 : 234
```

Is there any way to make them aligned properly?

Comment: Could you add enough code, or perhaps a stackblitz project to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You can try css property { white-space: nowrap; }.

Comment: @Nesar I'm assigning this string to tooltip property of button , not sure if we can add class to tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because theres a bunch of random spaces in your string

Try

```
toolTip =`${'string'}  : ${123}
${'string'}  : ${123}
${'string'}  : ${123}
${'string'}  : ${123}
${'string'}  : ${123}`;
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9szvet?file=src/app/app.component.ts